# Share .iso files on CentOS for remote mounting anywhere via Internet

Tags: linux, centos, webdav, iso, daemontools

I have a remote computer suppport business and we have the need to remotely mount .iso files on a client machine from time to time for use to grab driver updates and so on. We own a huge server on the Netcraft top 10 list and I'd like to mount some ISOs on this thing and use technology like WebDAV or something to mount them on a remote PC. It doesn't make sense, for example, for us to download the DriverPack Solution 4GB DVD to a machine and then scan/update the drivers. We would rather mount the image like a Google Drive.... Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for killing your client's internet connection.

Comment: Do you really need to mount the ISOs on the client machines and not the server?  If you could just mount them on the server and share the mounted isos out, it might be a lot easier.  You could probably even do something with autofs to make the mounting automatic.

Answer (score 5):

Sound do'able - just put the .ISO file/s on an read-only NFS/CIFS/HTTP share, mount that on the servers as needed and then open the .ISO - or you could just put the contents of the .ISO on the same share of course.

Comment: For Windows clients before 8 or Server 2012 he'll have to use contents, though that's unlikely to be a problem as most things these days don't use absolute linking.

Comment: unless he installed an ISO reader on those earlier OS's.